# Align Group blocks left or right

Tags: block-editor

I'd like to right-align a Group block within a wide column. Is there a way I can get the Groups to show the same alignment options as an Image block does?

[image: screenshot of available alignment options for an image block]

Group blocks by default only provide "Wide Width" and "Full Width". I'm able to do the corresponding CSS myself, I just need an interface for the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a way to do this after [browsing the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/group). I do note that the code that helped me lives under `deprecated.js` so it's possible this won't continue to work.

Here's the JS code I have in my plugin directory

```js
function addAlignmentToGroups(settings, name) {
    if (name !== "core/group") {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        supports: lodash.assign( {}, settings.supports, {
            align: ['wide', 'full', 'left', 'center', 'right']
        })
    });
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'myapp/alignments/group-block',
    addAlignmentToGroups
);
```

And the PHP code to load it:

```php
<?php

 function my_enqueue() {
     wp_enqueue_script(
         'my-align-blocks',
         plugins_url('dist/align-blocks.js', __FILE__),
         ['wp-blocks']
     );
 }

 add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_enqueue');
```